# Is it possible to merge AST transform visitors consistently?

Tags: algorithm, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern

Given two visitors A and B that sequentially apply transformations to a given AST, is it always possible to automatically merge A and B into a single visitor that, by applying A and B node by node, gives the same result?

If it depends on the situation, what exactly are the conditions required on A and B?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm finding the description confusingly vague. Exactly what transformations can one of these visitors do to this AST?  Useful transformations may look like "find common subexpressions" which emphatically are NOT just "apply something node by node".

Comment: I was talking about just any visitor you can imagine. So this answers my question. The answer is no, every visitor can have its own traversal logic, so it wouldn't make sense to always merge them together and force a specific traversal algorithm on them.

Comment: Libraries like estraverse and babel have utilities to merge visitors, hence my question. If you know what kind of assumption they make on the visitors to make that generically possible, I'd be curious to know, the doc doesn't talk about it.